# Change annotations on MKMapView on zoom out

Tags: android, ios, annotations, mapkit, android-mapview

I have some custom annotations and annotation views that I have added on my mapview, I want to swap those with standard pin annotations when the user zooms out.

At present I am able to detect a zoom out, the bit I'm struggling on is how to do the actual swap. I.e. how do I remove the custom annotations and replace them with standard pins.

Comment: @kiamlaluno  : Is there any way to identify whether mapview is zoomed in or out?